# Is there any need to encrypt data being passed to Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, security, encryption

We have Azure Blob Storage with encryption at rest and infrastructure encryption enabled. We have a ASP NET Core application which passes confidential files (mostly pdf or docx documents) to and from the Azure storage for upload and viewing respectively.

We have also implemented AES encryption of the files before they are passed to Azure for upload however we are wondering if this is overkill and just an unnecessary hit on performance when we already have encryption through Azure.

Does our local AES encryption of files before passing to Azure add anything to the security? Or is it just a pointless exercise and drain on performance?

Documents are stored in memory stream before being uploaded and never stored on a local disk or as a physical file.

Comment: How much do you trust Microsoft? Does your privacy policy state that Microsoft has access to the data (by default azure storage uses keys managed by microsoft so Microsoft is able to decrypt the data if they want to or the government forces them).

Answer (score 0):

Notable points - 
`Encryption in transit` - HTTPS (make sure you're on TLS 1.2) 
`Encryption at rest` - Microsoft uses 256-bit AES. However, instead of AES-ing something that would eventually again be AES-ed by Microsoft, you can use your own keys to encrypt the data at rest (BYOK / CMK) by using REST calls to upload the files and specifying your own `KEY` by using `x-ms-encryption-key` header. 
More info is available here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/encryption-customer-provided-keys#request-headers-for-specifying-customer-provided-keys